# Handling comma separated strings as a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, reporting-services

I'm using SSRS with MySQL and need to handle the multi-select parameters from SSRS going into my routines (stored procedures) in MySQL.

SSRS passes a multi-select parameter as a comma separated string:

"1,2,3,4"

The common way this is done in SQL Server is by using a table-valued function that would return a table with a row for each value. You then join to this table and all is well.

What is the best way to handle this situation in MySQL, due to the fact that it does not have an equivalent table valued function?

I have seen suggestions to use a temp table in a function, however I will have multiple simultaneous calls of this so that will most likely not work.

Comment: Best way to handle this situation is to ***not*** pass a comma delimited string.

Comment: SSRS uses .net types, in this instance an array. So if I have a user select 25 states, how would you suggest I pass that array into MySQL? The commonly accepted method for SQL Server is a comma delimted string. AFAIK, comma delimited string in this case is the best way to deal with database apps that do not have an array type. Let me know what your solution is.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, although I aggree to a degree **I do not agree** wirh you response. With your wealth of knowledge can't you spare a moment to assist, even if to a resource?

Comment: Pass as individual values. Create n possible variables. Any unused variables would be null

Comment: @DonBecker, i dont know how to help you but i tried to get some help for you. Im not sure of its worth but i tried.  :(